# Why constants in python changed?

Tags: python, string, variables, syntax, constants

A constant is a variable whose value stays the same throughout the life of a
program. Python doesn’t have built-in constant types, but Python programmers
use all capital letters to indicate a variable should be treated as a constant
and never be changed:

```
num1=20
NUM =40
print(NUM)
if num1 >10:
    NUM = NUM-5
print(NUM)
```

**output**
40
35

i expect not change
still 40 not 35 or get error

Comment: You said it yourself. “Python doesn’t have built-in constant types, but Python programmers use all capital letters to indicate a variable should be treated as a constant and never be changed”. It’s a convention, so don’t change it.

Comment: What do you mean? I think only numbers, characters and objects' classes are constants. And what do you mean by "but Python programmers use all capital letters to indicate a variable should be treated as a constant and never be changed"? If I'm not wrong, a variable's name doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, what do you mean? Are you sarcastically asking the OP not to change `NUM`'s value in the code, or is it something else? Does the variable's name really matter?

Comment: Python doesn’t have constant variables so if you want it to be constant, don’t change it.  Hence the convention.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, okay, LOL. Sorry, didn't see the edit :P

Comment: "Python programmers use all capital letters to indicate a variable should be treated as a constant and never be changed." <--- This shows how python creator and their followers treat programmers like kids. It would be better to say "Unfortunately, Python doesn't support the concept of constant yet, so it's all programmer's responsibility of managing mutability of variables." or "In Python sense, why would you need a constant if you can keep it unchanged consciously without mistakes?"

Answer (score 2):

"Should never be changed" isn't the same as "can never be changed".  The actual language spec of Python does not have a mechanism to create a variable that can never be reassigned.

Giving a variable an ALL_CAPS name is sort of a "promise" (an unenforced one) to people reading your code who are familiar with Python conventions that this is a global variable that won't change unexpectedly.  Think of it as a shorthand for sticking a comment after it like this:

```
NUM = 40  # subsequent code won't modify this value, I pinky-swear
```

The Python interpreter doesn't prevent you from lying in comments, and it doesn't prevent you from doing things that are against the commonly accepted conventions of the language.

Answer (score 0):

const = ("const value",0)

const[0] = 1 #gives an error

var1 = const[0]

var1 = 1 #changes only the value of var1

print(const[0]) #output: "const value"

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing `const = ("I changed it", 1)`, though...  You can't mutate a tuple, but you can still reassign any variable that points to it.  (And note that you can't mutate a regular old int or string either!  Putting something in a tuple doesn't make it any more or less mutable.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).